# Display image at the same size across different desktop resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to display an image of a card which is credit card sized, it has to be the same size across all desktop resolutions , so that means it needs to display the image at the same width and height of the physical card.

I have investigated how easy it would be to turn physical mm to px and resize the image but this is a lot more complicated than first thought.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The issue here is not one of just screen resolution, but also screen size.  For example a 21" and a 24" monitor would both typically have a 1920x1080 resolution, therefore a 20px square will appear smaller on the 21", however the computer itself doesn't actually need to know the physical size of the screen (although it sometimes does), and therefore it's difficult if not impossible to accurately predict what size something will appear on the screen. You can use CSS mm with print, but on screen I believe it's just an approximation based on standard pixel densities. Sorry to not be more helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `mm` ( as milimeters ) instead of `px` in css width and height. as far as i know, css supports that.  in [this](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/units.html) document, it is pointed out however that "Absolute length units are highly dependent on the output medium, and so are less useful than relative units.". But it is as close to precise as you can get, IMHO.

Comment: You could also use cm, inches, etc. see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537660(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: check http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/units.html as well... i'm not sure if css on microsoft site isn't exclusively for IE. there might be differences, i don't know.

Comment: Use of physical units in css is only really recommended for print as they do not always output at the size expected (http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)

Comment: @Ben : it is as close to precise as it gets.

Comment: Sadly it probably is, but with ever increasing pixel densities it's probably not too accurate these days, dread to think what it does on a MacBook with Ratina display

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a cross-browser solution but it should work with most browsers.

HTML:

```
<img id="image" src="img.jpg" />
```

CSS:

```
#image {
    height:inherit;
    width:inherit;
}
```

That should give your image the same width and height as the parent DIV. So your image must be contained in a div with the exact height and width of the image.

Comment: You can give `height` and `width` directly in the `HTML` too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, i suspected after investigation that this wouldnt be possible. Sizing in mm doesnt appear to work consistently enough so i may have to concead defeat on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [viewport units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length) such as vw, vh, vmin, vmax:

```
img{
   width: 2vw;
   height: 2vw;
}
```

Now, if you see the image in any resolution, this will be the same.

- vh - 1/100th of the height of the viewport.
- vw - 1/100th of the width of the viewport.
- vmin - 1/100th of the minimum value between the height and the width
  of the viewport.
- vmax - 1/100th of the maximum value between the height and the width
  of the viewport.

Also see, [can i use viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)